# iPhone UI templates?

Tags: iphone, templates, interface, components

Are there any UI templates for iPhone components available? I would like to globally change the appearance of a component (e.g. UIButton). What is the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a custom control of your class and override drawRect method. There is no specific template etc in SDK itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can look in Interface Builder for most of not all of the UI styles. Other than that, you need to pull out Photoshop and design skins and use them in your subclassed controls.